# Accessing conditionally rendered canvas element in React for plotting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm relatively new to React and am stumped trying to integrate third party plotting libraries into my application, in this instance `chartjs`. (note: I have looked at similar questions on here but was unable to glean a solution from them)

I need to create an plot instance that targets the context of a HTML canvas element. I'm using React's ref prop to try to implement this behaviour but I think I'm being tripped up by the asynchronicity of React's methods. It seems that `ctx.current` is always null in the `render()` method. I've also tried placing the `chart()` call in `componentDidMount` but then this.ctx is undefined, presumably because the conditional rendering hasn't occurred yet so the ref doesn't exist?

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {data: [], labels: []}

        this.ctx = React.createRef();

        this.fakeAPICall();
    }

    // retrieve fascinating data...
    fakeAPICall = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Data fetched');
            this.setState({
                data: [1,2,3],
                labels: ['A', 'B', 'C']
            })
        }, 1500);
    }

    chart = () => {
        console.log('creating chart')
        const myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: this.state.labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Series 1',
                    data: this.state.data
                }]
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.ctx && this.ctx.current) this.chart();

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Fascinating Chart</h1>
                {
                    this.state.data.length
                        ?
                        <canvas
                            ref={c => {
                                this.ctx = c.getContext('2d')}
                            }
                            style={{ width: 400, height: 200 }}
                        />
                        :
                        <p>Loading ...</p>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

My current best attempt is attached here in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/327056/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because there are no further state updates after you assign the ref to the `canvas`; that means no more re-renderings (calls to render method) so you never get to execute `this.chart()`. Instead of calling that last method in render, add it to the `setState` callback in `fakeAPICall`:

```
this.setState({
    data: [1,2,3],
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C']
}, () => this.chart());
```

The callback will be executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered. You can read more about state callbacks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Thanks very much, well explained and has fixed it for me.